# Get property from MS Project

Tags: c#, ms-project

There is a way to get the information from my project properties that I choose, for example normally MS Project count 20 days in a month and 8h of work in a day but I can modify these values, is it a way to get these values dynamically?

Comment: Rachel's answer is spot on.  Also  be aware of potential mismatch issues with calendar working time.  Simply changing the hours per day and days per month properties only affects how the MS Project user interface translates your inputs into the native time starage units (minutes).  When the scheduling engine assigns the entered units to assignments things can get messy quickly.  See my article here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ms-project-its-time-malcolm-farrelle/

Comment: Yes, I know
I just read this setting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project properties for these are [Project.DaysPerMonth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-dayspermonth-property-project)  and [Project.HoursPerDay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/project-hoursperday-property-project?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Both are read/write, Double.